# Match variable passed to directive dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a directive for an HTML image which allows me to store URLs and alt tags for images I use a lot, so I only have to give it a specific value via its data field (data-type in the code) and it gets replaced by an image with corresponding URL and alt tag. I'm doing this so I don't have to write out the tags all of the time and can change it at one place in the code.

So far it works great as long as I pass the value as a string. But for the directive to be really useful I need it to also work with passing the value as a variable (eg inside ng-repeat).

Here is my setup:

Directive - builds img based on a passed variable named type:

```
app.directive('tsTypeImage', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            type: '='
        },
        template:'<img src="{{ type.imgURL }}" alt="{{ type.name }}">'
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.fire = { name: "Fire", imgURL: "/images/fire.png" };
    $scope.water = { name: "Water", imgURL: "/images/water.png" };
    $scope.lightning = { name: "Lightning", imgURL: "/images/lightning.png" };

});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="tcgApp" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="type='fire'">

    <!-- this works -->
    <ts-type-image data-type="fire"></ts-type-image>

    <!-- this does not work -->
    <ts-type-image data-type="{{ type }}"></ts-type-image>

</body>
```

I already tried a lot of stuff with interpolate or parse but wasn't successful. This is my first AngularJS project so maybe I'm even running into the wrong direction and there is a much simpler way to achieve this. If so, please tell me :)

Comment: It would be wiser to use one-way (`<`) binding instead of two-binding (`=`) binding in the directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix interpolation with AngularJS expressions:

```
<body ng-app="tcgApp" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="type='fire'">

    <!-- this works -->
    <ts-type-image data-type="fire"></ts-type-image>

    <!-- this does not work -->
    ̵<̵t̵s̵-̵t̵y̵p̵e̵-̵i̵m̵a̵g̵e̵ ̵d̵a̵t̵a̵-̵t̵y̵p̵e̵=̵"̵{̵{̵ ̵t̵y̵p̵e̵ ̵}̵}̵"̵>̵<̵/̵t̵s̵-̵t̵y̵p̵e̵-̵i̵m̵a̵g̵e̵>̵
    <ts-type-image data-type="this[type]"></ts-type-image>

</body>
```

Use the `this` identifier in AngularJS expressions to access the `$scope` object.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expression context](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my problem. I will read more on expression context!